# Regex first letter of each word Upper Case separated by spaces and 3 to 29 character long...C#

Tags: c#, regex

I recently was assigned an impossible task (in my estimation) to create a regex pattern in which I should be able to validate several words in the same sentence or textbox with the following guidelines:

- Each name/word has to have first letter upper case
- Names/Words separated by spaces
- Each name/word 3 characters long or more
- And the sentence or textbox text can't be longer than 20 characters

Example: `Joseph Gordon Levitt`

This example is exactly 20 characters long, each name (or word) is longer than 3 characters, separated by spaces, and the first letter of each name (or word) is upper case.

I tried this regex pattern `^[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z\s]{3,20}$`. It works for some strings, but not all.

Comment: Hi, did my solution work for you? Note you may replace `\p{Lu}` with `[A-Z]` and `\p{L}` with `[A-Za-z]` if you only want to match ASCII letters, and use any pattern from my answer that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of options is this:

```
^(?!.{21})[A-Z][a-z]{2,}(\s[A-Z][a-z]{2,})*$
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oWjSI4

[image]

Comment: This is just a variation of my `^(?!.{21})\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,})*$` regex that does not support Unicode letters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I did help very well

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through the requirements:

- *Each name/word has to have first letter upper case*:  Use **`\p{Lu}`**
- *Names/Words separated by spaces*: Use **`\s+` (1 or more spaces) / `\s` (only single space)**
- *Each name/word 3 characters long or more*: Word pattern will thus be **`\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}`** - starting with an uppercase and then having 2 or more letters
- *And the sentence or textbox text can't be longer than 20 characters*: Use a positive lookahead right after `^` / `\A` (start of string): **`(?!.{21})`** or **`(?=.{0,20}$)`**.

The resulting regex will look like

```
^(?!.{21})\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,})*$
^(?=.{0,20}$)\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,})*$
```

Or, if there can be 1+ whitespaces between words

```
^(?!.{21})\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,})*$
^(?=.{0,20}$)\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,})*$
```

**NOTE**: If you ever test it against a string that can end with a `\n`, newline char, replace `$` with `\z`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F!.%7B21%7D%29%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B2%2C%7D%28%3F%3A%5Cs%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B2%2C%7D%29*%24&i=Joseph%20Gordon%20Levitt).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{0,20}$)` - there must be 0 to 20 non-newline chars in the string till the end
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `\p{L}{2,}` - two or more letters
- `(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,})*` - 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `\s` - a whitespace (or 1+ whitespaces if `\s+` is used)
  - `\p{Lu}\p{L}{2,}` - an uppercase letter and then any two or more letters
- `$` - end of string (`\z` is the very end of the string).